# model.save() not working using Mongoose and MongoDB Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to using MongoDB, and trying to save some data into MongoDB Atlas using Mongoose. I am possibly doing something blatantly wrong, but I do not understand why it is not working. I get no response from it, no error.
Here is the code:

File 1:

```
const SavedGuild = require('./models/guild.js');

module.exports = new class {
  async get(id) {
    return await SavedGuild.findById(id)
      || await new SavedGuild({ _id: id }).save();
  }
}
```

(I have tried `SavedGuild({ _id: id }).markModified("guild").save()`, same result)

File 2 (./models/guild.js):

```
const { model } = require('mongoose');

class GeneralModule {
  prefix = '/';
  blacklistedChannelIds = [];
}

module.exports = model('guild', {
  _id: String,
  general: { type: Object, default: new GeneralModule() }
});
```

Mongoose is initiated with this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

try {
  mongoose.connect(
    `${process.env.mongourl}`,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => console.log("Mongoose is connected")
  );
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Mongoose could not connect");
}
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: What does `findById` return when there are no matches?

Comment: `new SavedGuild({ _id: id }).save();` what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @PankajTanwar I am trying to create a new MongoDB document/value with _id being the Discord guild id given when the function is run.

Comment: @Joe Nothing, I think because the new document/value isn't being created.